# Container view not properly binding to size constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard, uicontainerview

I have an issue with one of my container views. I have 2 container views. Both load up nicely and everything works as intended. However after I started testing it on different models [I started getting this behavior.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgH7H.jpg) The top container for some reason resizes it's width to god-knows-what. The storyboard clearly says that the top and bottom container are the same width. It has that constraint built into the storyboard so I dont know why it's doing that.
These are the constraints on each one:
TOP CONTAINER VIEW:

- Proportional Height to Superview
- Alight center X to safe area
- Align trailing to: safe area = 5
- Align leading to safe area = 5
- Bottom space to CONTAINER BOT = 20
- Top space to TEXTFIELD = 15
- Equal Width to: CONTAINER BOT

==FOR THE BOTTOM CONTAINER==

- Alignt Center X to: superview
- Bottom space to superview = 50
- Top space to CONTAINER TOP = 20
- Equal width to: CONTAINER TOP

Also. On the view did load I have the following:

```
func setupViews() {
    containedView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    containedView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    containedView.clipsToBounds = true
    containerViewBot.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    containerViewBot.layer.masksToBounds = true
    containerViewBot.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: How did you setup your view controllers? And you should show all of the constraints of these 2 views otherwise none should be able to help.

Comment: modified OP to clarify constraints and setup

Comment: You have ambiguous constraints setup for your **TOP CONTAINER VIEW**. When you provide top & bottom constraints, you can't provide height constraint. And when you provide leading & trailing constraints, you can't provide center x and/or width constraint.